# SNOMED CT Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, snomed-ct

I am looking to figure out how to build a qualitative dataset based on cause effect relationships.

For the causes, i want to consider Findings and Symptoms and for the effects i want to consider diseases and disorders.

I have imported the SNOMED CT data into Neo4J DB using the scripts provided by SNOMED International (https://github.com/IHTSDO) (https://github.com/IHTSDO/snomed-database-loader/tree/master/NEO4J).

The Ontology has been downloaded from the official NLM website(https://www.nlm.nih.gov/healthit/snomedct/us_edition.html).

What would the cypher queries look for this?

Other details -

1. SNOMED CT US Data version = 20230301
2. Neo4J desktop on Mac OS X running db version `4.4.22`

Comment: Need more detail. Have you loaded the ontology to Neo4j yet? This is a complex projct likely needing enhancements to create a knowledge graph. How that is done depends on your questions.